# Smoothly grow parent div to height of added child div - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked all over this website for an explanation of what I am trying to achieve but have yet found an answer that fits my situation.

I have a div that is an alert box for a form validation

```
<div id="alert_box" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" 
     style="margin-top:0px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important; 
     display:none;">
//Alert message goes in here
</div>
```

The div is set to display if there is an error in the form. The height of this div is auto. It is inside a parent div with several other divs

```
<div id="parent_div">
   <div id="alert_box" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" 
            style="margin-top:0px !important; margin-bottom:0px !important; 
            display:none;">
           //Alert message goes in here
   </div>
   <div id="other_1">
   </div>
   <div id="other_2">
   </div>
   <div id="other_3">
   </div>
</div>
```

When the div is set to display I want it to grow the parent div smoothly. Currently it pops into the parent div.

Here is an example of my current password validation

```
function validatePassword(fld) {
       var input_div = document.getElementById('createPassword_div');
       var alert_box = document.getElementById('alert_box');

       if (fld.value == "") {
          input_div.className += ' has-error'; 
          alert_box.style.display = 'block';
          alert_box.innerHTML = "You didn't enter a password";
          return false;
       } 

       return true;
    }
```

How can I make the parent div grow smoothly when the child div is set to appear?

Comment: share your complete `HTML`.

Comment: Use any animation in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#error").html("Error Message").hide();
        $("#error").slideDown();
    }, 1000);
})
```

```css
.temp{
    height: 50px;
}

#error{
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id=parentDiv>
    <div id=error></div>
    <div class=temp>ABCD EDFG</div>
    <div class=temp>ABCD EDFG</div>
    <div class=temp>ABCD EDFG</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tell me if this is somewhere close to what you are looking for.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. But is there a way to check if the error div is already displayed?

Comment: $('#error').is(":hidden") will give you true if it is hidden and false otherwise